# Comma in an equation coincides on the equation number

Tags: equations, equation-number

The comma after the equation coincides with the number of the equation using the `eqnarray` . How can get rid of that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
    S_{EMS}=\frac{1}{16 \pi G_4} \int_{\mathcal{l}} \mathrm{d^4}x \ \sqrt{-r}  \ \left[p - \frac{f(\xi)}{4}D_{MN}D^{MN} -\frac{1}{2}\partial_{M}\phi \partial^{l}\xi -V(\phi)\right],
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should avoid `eqnarray` to begin with.

Comment: I wrote an article about why one should not use `eqnarray`: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf, the feature you observe is listed as one of the annoying parts of it. It should only be used in legacy docs. In new docs use `amsmath` and the constructions there in. Say for example `align`, will move the equation number if needed.

Comment: you ask about `eqnarray` but show `flalign` (neither should be used for a one-line equation) please make your example match your question

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: \begin{flalign} on input line 4 ended by \end{document}.`

Comment: Did you mean to write `\mathcal{L}` instead of `\mathcal{l}`? Unless you're using a specialized math font, `\mathcal{l}` will not produce what you think it should...

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you get? Running your code, I don't see a problem with the equation number and the comma https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjYZL.png