# Comma after an equation coincides with the equation number

Tags: equations, equation-number

The comma after the equation coincides with the number of the equation using the `eqnarray` . How can get rid of that?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath} 
    \begin{document}
    \begin{eqnarray}
        S_{EMS}=\frac{1}{16 \pi G_4} \int_{\mathcal{l}} \mathrm{d^4}x \ \sqrt{-r}  \ \left[p - \frac{f(\xi)}{4}D_{MN}D^{MN} -\frac{1}{2}\partial_{M}\phi \partial^{l}\xi -V(\phi)\right],
\end{eqnarray}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: why did you delete the previous copy of this question?

Comment: @David Carlisle, I was unable to edit that.

Comment: duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694518/comma-in-an-equation-coincides-on-the-equation-number

Comment: I wrote an article about why you should not use `eqnarray`. It lists this observation as one of the deficiencies in `eqnarray`. See https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf

Comment: Did you mean to write `\mathcal{L}` instead of `\mathcal{l}`? Unless you're employing a highly unusual math font, `\mathcal{l}` will *not* produce what you may think it should.

Answer (score 3):

`eqnarray` should be avoided in general, and if used should have two `&` on each row. But single line equations use `equation`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath} 
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        S_{\mathrm{EMS}}=\frac{1}{16 \pi G_4} \int_{\mathcal{L}} \mathrm{d^4}x  \sqrt{-r}  
 \left[p - \frac{f(\xi)}{4}D_{MN}D^{MN} -\frac{1}{2}\partial_{M}\phi \partial^{l}\xi -V(\phi)\right],
\end{equation}
    \end{document}
```